# PHP Preg Replace Line In Between

Tags: php, mysql

```
<p>Inspection and treatment will be conducted to areas prone to Mouse infestation by our Service Specialist during the routine visits. This includes the sewerage system servicing the property.</p>

<p>Apart from treating the sewerage manhole, application of residual coat will also be done at strategic areas prone to Mouse activity/harborages, and when necessary, baits will be placed and application of gel will be carried out.</p>

<p>Preparations used are safe to humans and animals and is approved by the Ministry.</p>
```

Above is my text to record into mysql, I want to trim them into

```
<p>Inspection and treatment will be conducted to areas prone to Mouse infestation by our Service Specialist during the routine visits. This includes the sewerage system servicing the property.</p><p>Apart from treating the sewerage manhole, application of residual coat will also be done at strategic areas prone to Mouse activity/harborages, and when necessary, baits will be placed and application of gel will be carried out.</p><p>Preparations used are safe to humans and animals and is approved by the Ministry.</p>
```

I used the following code:

```
$service_desc = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $service_desc);
```

However the code does not solve the spacing in between text of the string, how can I remove the white space in between to achieve the result I want.

Thanks!

Comment: It is `\n`, new line.

Comment: Do you want `</p><p>` (without space) or `</p> <p>` (with space)? Because your regex would replace whitespace (including newlines) with one single space, but your example output does not have a space between `p` tags.

Comment: why r u not use css for this? why preg replace?

Comment: Do you want to remove the whitespaces *in the code* – i.e. `</p><p>` – or do you want to remove the margins between paragraphs *after rendering?* Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to erase de end of line character, isn't this easier ?

```
$service_desc = str_replace("\r\n", '', $service_desc);
```

or

```
$service_desc = str_replace("\n", '', $service_desc);
```

Sorry if this isn't what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using `CSS` with `margin` set as 0:

```
<style type="text/css">
p { margin:0 }
</style>
```

```css
p { margin:0 }
```

```html
<p>Inspection and treatment will be conducted to areas prone to Mouse infestation by our Service Specialist during the routine visits. This includes the sewerage system servicing the property.</p>

<p>Apart from treating the sewerage manhole, application of residual coat will also be done at strategic areas prone to Mouse activity/harborages, and when necessary, baits will be placed and application of gel will be carried out.</p>

<p>Preparations used are safe to humans and animals and is approved by the Ministry.</p>
```

Comment: Reread the question. The desired output still contains three paragraphs, just without (invisible) spaces inbetween.

Comment: @Lumen: did you checked snippet?? it contains. all paragraph, u can not remove by using regex or str_replace..

Comment: You’re removing the visible vertical space between paragraphs after rendering, but the OP wants to remove the invisible space in the source code (if I understand him correctly, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove space between tags, use

```
$text = preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $text);
```

This also removes space between inline tags such as two adjacent `<span>` elements, which might not be what you want.

Comment: did you check this solution on FireFox? its not worknig... same spaces display on browser.

Comment: @devpro The question doesn’t have to do anything with rendering in browsers, does it? My code turns the example input given by the OP into the desired output.